# How to add a delete button for newly displayed objects in an array

Tags: javascript, dom

i have a simple library app. i have an array that contains all my "book" objects and will also have functionality to add more objects to the array which will then be displayed as table rows. I need a delete function that targets the rows the the table but also newly created rows.

```js
function Book(name, author, ReadOrNot) {
    this.name = name
    this.author = author
    this.ReadOrNot = ReadOrNot
}

const book1 = new Book("The Hobbit", "J.R.R Tolkien", "Read")
const book2 = new Book("A Game of Thrones", "George R.R. Martin", "Not read")
const book3 = new Book("Jane Eyre", "Charlotte Brontë", "Read")

let myLibrary = []

function addBookToLibrary(...arr) {
 myLibrary.push(...arr)
}

addBookToLibrary(book1)
addBookToLibrary(book2)
addBookToLibrary(book3)


function addBookToTable(){
    let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody')
    myLibrary.forEach(b =>{
      let tr = document.createElement('tr')
      let content = '<td>' + b.name + '</td><td>' + b.author + '</td>'
      if(b.ReadOrNot == 'Read'){
        content += '<td><button id="readbtn" class="btn rdbtn">Read</button></td>'  
       }
       else if(b.ReadOrNot == 'Not read'){
         content += '<td><button id="readbtn" class="btn rdbtn">Not read</button></td>'
       }
       content += '<td><button class="btn delbtn" onclick="toggleDelete()">Delete</button></td>'
      tr.innerHTML = content
      tbody.appendChild(tr)
     })
  }
  
  addBookToTable()
```

```html
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Author</td>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td>      </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
       
        <tbody>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You want delete function only which will delete a targeted row?

Comment: Yes. every row will have a delete button that removes the targeted row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a simple approach and just defining your already declared `toggleDelete()` function.

1. Remove a row

```js
function Book(name, author, ReadOrNot) {
  this.name = name
  this.author = author
  this.ReadOrNot = ReadOrNot
}

const book1 = new Book("The Hobbit", "J.R.R Tolkien", "Read")
const book2 = new Book("A Game of Thrones", "George R.R. Martin", "Not read")
const book3 = new Book("Jane Eyre", "Charlotte Brontë", "Read")

let myLibrary = []

function addBookToLibrary(...arr) {
  myLibrary.push(...arr)
}

addBookToLibrary(book1)
addBookToLibrary(book2)
addBookToLibrary(book3)


function addBookToTable() {
  let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody')
  myLibrary.forEach(b => {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr')
    let content = '<td>' + b.name + '</td><td>' + b.author + '</td>'
    if (b.ReadOrNot == 'Read') {
      content += '<td><button id="readbtn" class="btn rdbtn">Read</button></td>'
    } else if (b.ReadOrNot == 'Not read') {
      content += '<td><button id="readbtn" class="btn rdbtn">Not read</button></td>'
    }
    content += '<td><button class="btn delbtn" onclick="toggleDelete(this)">Delete</button></td>'
    tr.innerHTML = content
    tbody.appendChild(tr)
  })
}
addBookToTable()

function toggleDelete(o) {
  var p = o.parentNode.parentNode;
  p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
}
```

```css
.hide-row {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Author</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

2. Hide/Show a row

```js
function Book(name, author, ReadOrNot) {
  this.name = name
  this.author = author
  this.ReadOrNot = ReadOrNot
}

const book1 = new Book("The Hobbit", "J.R.R Tolkien", "Read")
const book2 = new Book("A Game of Thrones", "George R.R. Martin", "Not read")
const book3 = new Book("Jane Eyre", "Charlotte Brontë", "Read")

let myLibrary = []

function addBookToLibrary(...arr) {
  myLibrary.push(...arr)
}

addBookToLibrary(book1)
addBookToLibrary(book2)
addBookToLibrary(book3)


function addBookToTable() {
  let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody')
  myLibrary.forEach(b => {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr')
    let content = '<td>' + b.name + '</td><td>' + b.author + '</td>'
    if (b.ReadOrNot == 'Read') {
      content += '<td><button id="readbtn" class="btn rdbtn">Read</button></td>'
    } else if (b.ReadOrNot == 'Not read') {
      content += '<td><button id="readbtn" class="btn rdbtn">Not read</button></td>'
    }
    content += '<td><button class="btn delbtn" onclick="toggleDelete(this)">Hide</button></td>'
    tr.innerHTML = content
    tbody.appendChild(tr)
  })
}
addBookToTable()

function toggleDelete(o) {
  var p = o.parentNode.parentNode;
  p.childNodes.forEach(elements => {
    elements.classList.toggle('hide-row');
  })
  p.childNodes[3].style = 'visibility : visible !important';
  if (p.childNodes[3].childNodes[0].parentNode.classList[0] == "hide-row") {
    p.childNodes[3].childNodes[0].innerHTML = 'Show';
  } else {
    p.childNodes[3].childNodes[0].innerHTML = 'Hide';
  }
}
```

```css
.hide-row {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Author</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You want to be able to identify each book by an id which you'll have to insert somewhere into your book object at some point. When you create your `update` and `delete` functions you'll be able to use that id to update the books array.

   1a) To update the status of a book you can [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the book in the books array, and then simply update its `status` value.

   1b) To delete a book you will need to [`find the index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) of the book, and then [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) that book from the books array.
2. When the books array is updated you will also need to re-render the HTML. And you can do that with the function you already have (although I've changed it in this example to use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). In the HTML you'll need to add a couple of [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes): the first to indicate the type (update/delete), and the second to indicate the book/row id.

Now, to make this all a bit easier it might make sense to create a new [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) called `Library` to which you can add books, handles all the book operations, and also creates the new HTML when a book is updated/deleted.

Note: I've used a class here instead of a function constructor to make the code a little easier to understand. Whether you keep working with constructors the principles as to *how* update/delete the books will remain the same.

```js
// New class!
class Library {
  
  // It accepts a root element - the tbody element
  // It creates a books array, and then adds an event listener
  // to the root element (ensuring we bind `this` properly)
  constructor(el) {
    this.books = [];
    this.el = el;
    this.el.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this));
  }

  // When the root element catches an event from one of its
  // child elements we check to see if it's a button
  // and then checks its type: either `update` or `delete`, and
  // calls a library method with the book it accordingly.
  handleClick(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('button')) {
      const { dataset: { id, type } } = e.target;
      if (type === 'update') {
        this.updateBook(id);
      }
      if (type === 'delete') {
        this.deleteBook(id);
      }
      this.updateHtml();
    }
  }

  // When you add a book we automatically assign
  // an id to it (the current length of the books array + 1)
  // We update the table
  addBook(book) {
    this.books.push({
      ...book,
      id: this.books.length + 1
    });
    this.updateHtml();
  }
  
  // If the update button was clicked we `find` it in the
  // books array, and set its status to either true/false
  updateBook(id) {
    const found = this.books.find(book => {
      return +book.id === +id;
    });
    if (found) found.status = !found.status;
  }

  // If the delete button was clicked we find the index
  // of the book in the books array, and then `splice` it out
  deleteBook(id) {
    const index = this.books.findIndex(book => {
      return book.id === +id;
    });
    if (index >= 0) this.books.splice(index, 1);
  }

  // Creates a new set of HTML from the books array, and
  // replaces the innerHTML of the root element with it
  // For each row we add the data attributes for the type, and
  // the id. Each of which will be used in the library's `handleClick`
  // method
  updateHtml() {
    this.html = this.books.map(book => {
      return `
        <tr>
          <td>${book.name}</td>
          <td>${book.author}</td>
          <td>
            <button data-type="update" data-id="${book.id}">
              ${book.status ? 'Read' : 'Not read'}
            </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button data-type="delete" data-id="${book.id}">
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      `;
    }).join('');

    this.el.innerHTML = this.html;

  }

}

// Creates a book object
class Book {
  constructor(name, author) {
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.status = false;
  }
}


// Cache the root element (the table body)
const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

// Create a new library from the Library class passing
// in the root element
const library = new Library(tbody);

// Use the library `addBook` method to add new books
library.addBook(new Book('The Hobbit', 'J.R.R Tolkien'));
library.addBook(new Book('A Game of Thrones', 'George R.R. Martin'));
library.addBook(new Book('Jane Eyre', 'Charlotte Brontë'));
```

```css
table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; }
td { width: 24%; padding: 0.2em; border: 1px solid #efefef;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Author</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use pop method:

```
 function deleteLastBookToLibrary() {
     myLibrary.pop()
 }
```

Comment: the pop method removes the last element/object in an array right? these objects, which are displayed as rows when entered into the array, all have a delete button. the button should remove the row.